# Android - issue with SmsManager

Tags: android

i am trying to call the Smsmanager then whenever i am trying to, there  comes a line through the word like it is penned through. with is the issue  there? please help me cordially. thank you.

Comment: The line is there because it has been depreciated. You can still use it though.

Comment: but i didn't work. only the catch information of try-catch has been showing.